# MySQL Query, select episode on random from top view movie, but based only if status = 0

Tags: mysql

can you help me MySQL query.

I have 3 tables. I will write only the rows that I need:

Serial

```
--------------
| ID | views |
--------------
| 1  | 12113 |
--------------
| 2  | 34    |
--------------
| 3  | 123   |
--------------
```

SerialReal

```
----------------
| ID | sorceID |
----------------
| 12 | 1       |
----------------
| 14 | 3       |
----------------
| 15 | 2       |
----------------
| 16 | 4       |
----------------
```

SerialRealEpisode

```
---------------------
| ID | srID | status|
---------------------
| 1  | 12   | 0     |
---------------------
| 2  | 12   | 1     |
---------------------
| 3  | 12   | 0     |
---------------------
```

- now all rows are INT, status is int but only 0, 1, 2;
- Serial.ID = SerialReal.sorceID
- SerialRealEpisode.srID = SerialReal.id

what I want is to get one SerialRealEpisode item (LIMIT 1) on RANDOM that status is 0. But this SerialRealEpisode item need to be from Serial, that is in the top 3 Serial, that have episodes with SerialRealEpisode.status = 0. Random is that it is from one of the top 3 Serial and one of the all episodes in these Serials

Any idea? Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this...

```
 SELECT views FROM (
 SELECT s.`views` FROM `serial` s INNER JOIN `serialreal` sr ON s.id = sr.`sourceid`
 INNER JOIN `serialrealepisode` sre ON sre.`srid` = sr.`id`
 WHERE sre.`status` = '0' GROUP BY s.`views` ORDER BY s.`views` DESC LIMIT 3
 ) AS tbl ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

First i am selecting top 3 serials in descending order and then selecting one random result from the result set of the inner query.

Hope this will help you out...

Comment: Super, this is what I need. I tune it a bit and seems to work good. Thanks! I cannot vote up for this, but hope other viewers to do up for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use below query

```
SELECT views form Serial as se 
INNER JOIN SerialReal as sr ON se.id=sr.sorceID 
INNER JOIN SerialRealEpisode as sre ON sr.id=sre.srID 
where sre.status=0
```

Comment: thanks Mani, but I need this one to return only 1 episode and to be on Random from top viewed serials, so in the end I want to get SerialRealEpisode.id from top 3. Also I see it is not based on most views. Event if I put ORDER BY views DESC do not get the episodes that are with status = 0 from top serials

Comment: desired output is data from just table SerialRealEpisode. Or just SerialRealEpisode.id.